# SSH Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, lan, openssh, scp

I have 2 ubuntu systems , 1 lan cable. I need to transfer data(FILE OR DIRECTORY) using lan cable.( Note : there is no online network connection) I tried using ethernet and connected both ends in systems and configured IPV4 IP address in both , installed openssh-server, the service status also shows online but I try to ssh it simply shows  '''ssh connection to host : network is unreachable''' I don't know what to do next. Is that I'm doing in a right way? If someone know anything about it just add your comments please!'

Comment: I take it your cable is a crossover.

Comment: We don't know what you're doing, other than some global ideas. At least add the output of `ifconfig` for the interface and `netstat -rn` on both machines to the question.

Comment: I just know I used straight cable next I'll gonna try to use crossover

Comment: @Chenmunka Don't all Gbit and + network cards automatically switch modes when directly connected these days? i.e. no crossover cable needed anymore? Also agreed, more information is needed on both hardware and configurations involved.

Comment: Try with `ssh -vvv` and add the log to your question.